# Why does my Player follow the OrthographicCamera

Tags: libgdx

My game renders a tiledmap. I let the OrthographicCamera change its position.x to the right and can see the background (the tiledmap) scroll. This is fine.

But other Objects (the player and some balls) do (visually) change their position corresponding to the camera. They should not move, because only the camera moves.

```
package com.me.drop;
import java.util.Iterator;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.PerspectiveCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttributes.Usage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Environment;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Material;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.Model;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.ModelInstance;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.attributes.ColorAttribute;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.environment.DirectionalLight;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g3d.utils.ModelBuilder;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Circle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Body;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.BodyDef.BodyType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Box2DDebugRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.CircleShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Fixture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;


public class MyTestGame extends Game {
   Texture dropImage;
   Texture bucketImage;
   Sound dropSound;
   Music rainMusic;
   SpriteBatch batch;
   OrthographicCamera camera;
   Rectangle bucket;
   Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
   long lastDropTime;


   Animator animator = new Animator();
   Body animatorBody;
   private Physics physics;

   public Environment environment;
  // public PerspectiveCamera cam;
   public Model model;
   public ModelBatch modelBatch;
   public ModelInstance instance;


   static final int WIDTH  = 1600;
   static final int HEIGHT = 960;
   public final static float ORTHO_SCALE=1;
   public final static float WORLD_SCALE=32;

   Ball balls[] = new Ball[10];
   Spieler player;


   @Override
   public void create() {

       environment = new Environment();
       environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
       environment.add(new DirectionalLight().set(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));


       glViewport = new Rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


      // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
      dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));
      bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

      // load the drop sound effect and the rain background "music"
      dropSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("drop.wav"));
      rainMusic = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("rain.mp3"));

      // start the playback of the background music immediately
      rainMusic.setLooping(true);
      rainMusic.play();

      // create the camera and the SpriteBatch
      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      //camera.setToOrtho(false, 400, 240);
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800/ORTHO_SCALE, 480/ORTHO_SCALE);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();


      ModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
      model = modelBuilder.createBox(5f, 5f, 5f,
          new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.GREEN)),
          Usage.Position | Usage.Normal);
      instance = new ModelInstance(model);

      // Box2d
      physics = Physics.getInstance();

      // floor
      physics.initFloor(0f, 0f, camera.viewportWidth, 0f);
      // ceiling
     // physics.initFloor(0f, camera.viewportHeight, camera.viewportWidth, 10f);
      // left Wall
      physics.initFloor(0f, 0f, 0f, camera.viewportHeight);
      // right Wall   
      physics.initFloor(camera.viewportWidth, 0f, 0f, camera.viewportHeight);


      float x = 150;
      float y = camera.viewportHeight;
      for (int i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
          if (i%10==0) {
              x += 10;
              y = camera.viewportHeight / 2;
          }
          y += x;
         balls[i] = new Ball(x, y , 20f , 20f, 0.4f, 0.8f);
      }
      player = new Spieler(50, camera.viewportHeight, 60f, 120f);

      loadBackground();
   }


   TiledMapRenderer tileRenderer;

   public void loadBackground() {
       TiledMap map = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/mymap.tmx");
       System.out.println(map.getTileSets().toString());
       float unitScale = 1 / 1;
       tileRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, unitScale);


       physics.createFixturesForMap(map);
   }




   private Rectangle           glViewport;


   //@Override
   public void render() {


      GL10 gl = Gdx.graphics.getGL10();

      // Camera --------------------- /
      gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      gl.glViewport((int) glViewport.x, (int) glViewport.y,
              (int) glViewport.width, (int) glViewport.height);
//


      // tell the camera to update its matrices.
      camera.update();
      camera.apply(gl);


      // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
      // coordinate system specified by the camera.
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);



   // background
      tileRenderer.setView(camera);
      tileRenderer.render();


      for (Ball b : balls)
          b.render();


      player.render();

      grabUserAction();


      // Box2d
      physics.step();
      updateObjects();
      physics.debugRenderer.render(physics.world, camera.combined);

   }

    private void grabUserAction() {
          // process user input
          if(Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
             Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
             touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
             camera.unproject(touchPos);
             bucket.x = touchPos.x - 64 / 2;
          }


        Vector2 vel = this.player.getBody().getLinearVelocity();
        Vector2 pos = this.player.getBody().getPosition();
        // apply left impulse, but only if max velocity is not reached yet
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)) { // && vel.x > -MAX_VELOCITY) {
            // this.animatorBody.localPoint2.x -= 200 *
            // Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            pos.x -= 2 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            this.player.getBody().setTransform(pos, 0);
            // this.animatorBody.applyLinearImpulse(0, -0.8f, pos.x, pos.y,
            // true);
            // this.animatorBody.applyLinearImpulse(-5000, 0, pos.x, pos.y,
            // true);
        }

        // apply right impulse, but only if max velocity is not reached yet
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)) { // && vel.x < MAX_VELOCITY) {
            // this.animatorBody.localPoint2.x += 200 *
            // Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            pos.x += 2 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            this.player.getBody().setTransform(pos, 0);
            // this.animatorBody.applyLinearImpulse(5000, 0, pos.x, pos.y,
            // true);

        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)) {
            Vector2 impuls = new Vector2(0, 500f);
            this.player.getBody().applyLinearImpulse(impuls, player.getBody().getWorldCenter(),true);
//          this.animatorBody.applyAngularImpulse(-5.0f, true);
            //(impulse, wake);(new b2Vec2(0.0, -3.0), Body.GetWorldCenter());
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) {
            this.camera.position.x += 2;
            this.camera.update();

        }
        else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) {
            this.camera.position.x -= 2;
            this.camera.update();
        }

    }

   private void updateObjects() {
       Array<Body> array = new Array<Body>();
       physics.world.getBodies(array);
       Iterator<Body> bi = array.iterator();

       while (bi.hasNext()){
           Body b = bi.next();


           // Get the body's user data - in this example, our user 
           // data is an instance of the Entity class
           IObject e = (IObject) b.getUserData();


           if (e != null) {
               // Update the entities/sprites position and angle
               e.setPosition((b.getPosition().x - e.getWidth()/2/WORLD_SCALE) * WORLD_SCALE 
                           , (b.getPosition().y - e.getHeight()/2/WORLD_SCALE) * WORLD_SCALE);
               // We need to convert our angle from radians to degrees
               //e.setRotation(MathUtils.radiansToDegrees * b.getAngle());
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      // dispose of all the native resources
      dropImage.dispose();
      bucketImage.dispose();
      dropSound.dispose();
      rainMusic.dispose();
      batch.dispose();

    //  modelBatch.dispose();
      model.dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
       super.resize(width, height);
//     
//     Vector3 oldpos = new Vector3(camera.position);
//     camera.setToOrtho(false,
//                        width/WORLD_SCALE,
//                        height/WORLD_SCALE);
//     camera.translate(oldpos.x-camera.position.x,oldpos.y-camera.position.y);
   }

   @Override
   public void pause() {
       super.pause();
   }

   @Override
   public void resume() {
       super.resume();
   }
}
```

Comment: Usually this happens if you multiply a wrong matrix to the object, check if you use the model matrix of the camera for your objects as well. If so try to load the identity for the other objects or their own matrices. Also you usually don't need to call glViewport in each iteration.

Comment: hmm..I don't understand the point. I am not setting any matrixes explicitly except batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);